# How can I hibernate in Ubuntu 17.10 (Acer Aspire E15)

Tags: hibernate, tuxonice

I have been trying to make my laptop capable of hibernation.

First I tried `sudo systemctl hibernate`, and it didn't work at all, then I tried `uswsusp`, and it shut down the computer and nothing else. Finally I installed TuxOnIce kernel and. Oh! It works! But only twice.

I installed it, then restarted the computer and it worked perfectly. I did it another time to be sure that it was not a fluke, and it worked again.

But the next time I tried it, it took 5 minutes and is still in progress. I even reinstalled the OS and the same process repeated again.

I have an Acer Aspire E15 with the secure boot disabled.

How can I reliably enable hibernation?

Comment: Have you reviewed the [official Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html)? In particular, do you have an active swap partition >= machine RAM? When you say that running `systemctl hibernate` doesn't work, what specifically are the error messages?

Comment: Hi and thanks, well, I have an swap partition about 10 GB and 4GB of RAM; when I run systemctl hibernate there is any error message, it only do anything.

Comment: Add that now, thehibernation in windows 10 in another partition do exactly the same, suspect that the error is in something shared like grub.

Comment: That you're system isn't generating error messages when failing to hibernate is unusual: a failure should be logged and viewable for the sake of troubleshooting. You might want to run `journalctl -b` the next time you have a failed hibernate condition, and look specifically for `ACPI` events. Separately, I'd recommend using **only** the native `hibernate` call, rather than using TuxOnIce to help limit the source of your problem. Finally, you mention potential BIOS issues, so I'd recommend reading [this documentation regarding BIOS troubleshooting](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BIOSandUbuntu).